# i want to composite a data hourly with 4 years data

Tags: python, pandas

i have hourly data from January 2018 - December 2021

i want to sum the data each hour for four years. i.e. in a day we have 2pm just one hour, right?.but, in 4 years(365*3+366=1461) we have 1461 hours. i want to sum a data in each hour (00.00 - 23.00) for four years. but i dont get the idea how to code. this is my code

```
binstas=pd.DataFrame(ch)
df = binstas.copy()
df['new_column'] = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-12-31 23:50:00', freq='1H'))
df = df.set_index('new_column')
```

my expectation with not actual data

```
00:00 = 23
01:00 = 45
..
..
23:00 = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

`Floor`/truncate the timestamp to hour and format using `strftime` then `groupby` and `sum`:

```
i = df.index.floor('H').strftime('%H:%M')
df.groupby(i).sum()
```

Comment: sorry sir. but it has attribute error said 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'floor'

Comment: @iyya Set the date column as an index before using the solution.